Page ... has an invalid "default" export
Im trying to npm run build my project but unexpected error occurs:
Type error: Page "src/app/aboutus/page.tsx" has an invalid "default" export:
  Type "AboutUsProps" is not valid.

Here's the code for that:
import Team from "@/components/AboutUs/Team";
import React from "react";

type AboutUsProps = {
    className: string;
};


const AboutUs = ({ className }: AboutUsProps) => {
    return (
        <div className={`${className} flex flex-row max-w-4xl mx-auto py-24 gap-4`}>
            <div className="gap-4 flex flex-col mt-4">
                <h1 className={`text-6xl font-medium`}>Officers</h1>
                <h2 className={`text-3xl text-gray-800 font-light`}>
                    The great people <br /> behind the organization
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
                <Team committee="Core" />
                <Team committee="Academics Committee" />
                <Team committee="Research Committee" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AboutUs;


Can somebody explain why this error happened and try to resolve it? Thank you!

The error does not match the code you shared

Yes, it looks like the error doesn't match the code that you shared, as there is no error nor typo in your code. Can you maybe provide a reproducible example?

Or maybe you are using NextJs?
